# Caption makes Table move in statsoc class

Tags: tables, captions, auxiliary-files

I am working in `statsoc.cls` (you can find it [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1467-9876/homepage/stylefile16_new.zip)). Here I show you a working file for the problem I am facing in my paper.

I have a table which has a long-ish caption (2-3 lines). Every time I compile my `.tex` file, the table moves a little to the right of the page. I think it is because the captions stop wrapping at some point.

```
\documentclass{statsoc}

%%%% Packages to be used
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig} 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{natbib, float}

\title{``Table keeps moving every time I compile''}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table moves a little everytime I compile. I think this is because I have a long caption, but I cannot figure out how to resolve this problem. As you can see I am using statsoc.cls. I can reset the table if I delete the .aux file and recompile}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I delete the .aux file and re-compile, it starts off as this:

[image]

Then after one compilation becomes

[image]

Then after many more

[image]

As I recompile, I make no changes inside the table environment, and work outside it. I believe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275734/long-captions-causes-table-to-shift-incrementally) question is exactly the same as mine, but the question got closed.

I am not sure if you need more information here. Let me know if you do.

There is an overleaf user who writes [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-journal-of-the-royal-statistical-society-series-c-applied-statistics/xhkktkrcfswc#.V6JSZJMrLoA)

> Note that if your document contains other LaTeX errors, the tables
>   will not be processed correctly. Therefore if you're getting an error
>   message about `Missing number` and `\statsocwidth@b` etc, comment out your
>   tables and correct other errors in your code first. Then uncomment
>   your table code, and hit "recompile from scratch" at the bottom of the
>   error/warning message window.

So apparently, every time there is an error, the tables go haywire, and you need to get rid of the aux file.

Comment: I have no problem with this code.

Comment: It works the first couple of times. But after like 10 or so times it starts behaving as such. Could you try a couple of times for me.

Comment: This class is very strange: it doesn't seem to accept any simple command such as `\vspace`.

Comment: @Bernard I am able to use \vspace in the class. But the problem persists.

Comment: @Greenparker but the class still very strange! please, do you realy need to use it?

Comment: @touhami Yes, sadly I have to use the class.

Comment: how do you want the output like 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: @touhami 2 is what it should look like I think.

Comment: what about writing a script that run (...)latex twice and delete the aux.

Comment: under windows you can run `pdflatex myfile.tex & pdflatex myfile.tex & del myfile.aux` for example

Comment: @Greenparker At each run after the second, the lengths increase by 3.65pt.

Comment: @egreg interesting and so weird. How do you suppose I can fix that?

Comment: This is clearly due to a spurious space somewhere. A bug in the class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a very obscure bug, due to a spurious space that gets inserted somewhere I couldn't find out. Due to this spurious space, every time the document is compiled, the width assigned to the caption increases by 3.65pt, which is exactly the width of a normal interword space in the selected font.

Here's a workaround.

```
\documentclass{statsoc}

%%%% Packages to be used
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\parbox}
  {\advance\@tempdima-\fontdimen2\font\parbox} % decrease the width!
  {}{}
\makeatother  

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig} 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{natbib, float}

\title{``Table keeps moving every time I compile''}
\author{Don't move!}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}
\caption{Table moves a little everytime I compile. 
  I think this is because I have a long caption, 
  but I cannot figure out how to resolve this problem.
  As you can see I am using statsoc.cls. I can reset
  the table if I delete the .aux file and recompile}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Greenparker More of a hack than a solution, but as this class is used only for submissions…